# using a bool to determine if a process is an infinite loop in c#

Tags: c#, boolean, infinite-loop

I am to write a bool function that takes the follow pseudo code and determines whether it is an infinite loop:

```
while a is not equal to b do
  increase a by 1
  decrease b by 1
```

Currently I have the following solution:

```
bool isInfiniteProcess(int a, int b) {    
  return (b == a || b - 1 > a) ? false : true;
}
```

When I consider all possible conditions I can find a condition this would work for but my test bed of hidden solutions says this is incorrect.  Is there something I'm missing?  Is there build function or library I can use to do this in c#?

Comment: Your method will fail for the case `a=1, b=4`. Steps; `a=1, b=4` `a=2, b=3`, `a=3, b=2`, `a=4, b=1`.. and so on. This is probably a better fit for another site however, it's not really a programming question, it's a logic question

Comment: I'm confused - are you trying to detect infinite loops in the general case or in very specific cases? (If it's the former, it's impossible).

Comment: `(b - a) % 2 != 0` based on what Rob showed as example.

Comment: Also just return !(b == a || b - 1 > a) - no need to explicitly compare to true and false.

Comment: @EJoshuaS it is a specific case as he has in his question

Comment: So the question is what values will cause that pseudocode to go into an infinite loop?

Comment: Correct @EJoshuaS I am trying detect when the pdeudocode goes into an  infinite loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be infinite if the two numbers never approach each other.

`a` always increases by 1, `b` always decreases by 1

**First Case:**

a == b

**2nd Case:**

If they are both positive then they will equal each other if `b` is at least 2 more than `a` and the sum of `a` and `b` is divisible by 2: So 2nd condition is:

(b-a) >=2 && ((b + a) % 2 == 0)

**3rd Case:**

Both are negative so `a` will get bigger and `b` will get smaller. The same rule applies as the 2nd case but we take the absolute value so we can make the 2nd case like this and it will work for both 2nd and 3rd case:

(abs(b)-abs(a)) >=2 && ((abs(b) + abs(a) % 2 == 0)

**4th Case:**

`a` is negative and `b` is positive: They will equal if sum of absolute value of `a` and `b` is divisible by 2:

(abs(a) + b) % 2 == 0

**5th Case:**

`a` is positive and `b` is negative: `a` will increase and `b` will decrease like this on a number line:

```
   <- b          a ->
<---------|---------->
```

since they are going away from each other, they will never equal.

**All cases with C# code:**

```
bool isInfiniteProcess(int a, int b) {
   // Case 1
   if( b == a )
      return false;

   // Case 2 and 3
   bool bothNegative = ( a < 0 && b < 0 );
   bool bothPositive = ( a > 0 && b > 0 );
   if (bothNegative || bothPositive) {
      if( ( Math.Abs( b ) - Math.Abs( a ) ) >= 2 && ( ( Math.Abs( b ) + Math.Abs( a ) % 2 == 0 ) ) )
         return false;
   }


   // Case 3
   if (a < 0 && b > 0 ) {
      if( ( Math.Abs( a ) + b ) % 2 == 0 )
         return false;
   }

   return true;
}
```

Not tested, I need to go home...

Comment: Or potentially just `return b < a || a % 2 != b % 2;`

Comment: @Rob that's pretty sexy I must say :)  so instead of equality, you went for inequality. I get the first condition  and the whole thing will work but how did you arrive at the 2nd action? It makes sense but how did you arrive at that and is there a reason why you went for inequality? Very cool though I must say.

Comment: @Rob your solution works in my test bed :)  Though I am still not really sure what case Your code handle that my original solution doesn't.  What does my solution return  return (b == a || b - 1 > a) ? false : true; not handle?

Comment: @CodingYoshi it comes from the fact that it'll be infinite when the numbers 'pass' each other, which means at one point the distance between their values will be one. We reduce the distance by 2 each pass. Thus, to avoid a 'passing', the numbers must be both even or both odd. However after explaining this, what's really important is that the *distance* between the numbers must not be odd. So it can be simplified further: `b < a || (a - b) % 2 == 1`

Comment: @MatthewMcGuff Your solution doesn't handle the situation where the numbers pass each other, for example `a = 1, b = 4`

Comment: @Rob Thanks for the explanation.  Appreciate it.

Comment: @CodingYoshi No worries mate